# List of parent and child into nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a list that I'd like to transform into a nested dictionary. The first element of the list is the parent, the second the child. Can I do this recursively without having to continue creating helper lists for each level? I feel so dumb not understanding this.

```
relations = [["basket", "money"],
             ["basket", "fruits"],
             ["fruits", "orange"],
             ["fruits", "apple"],
             ["basket", "vegetables"],
             ["vegetables", "bean"],
             ["vegetables", "tomato"],
             ["tomato", "red tomato"],
             ["tomato", "green tomato"],
             ["vegetables", "pepper"],
             ["sweets", "candy"]]


result = {}
running_list = []

for parent, child in relations:
    if parent == "basket":
        result[child] = {}
        running_list.append(child)

for parent, child in relations:
    if parent in running_list:
        result[parent] = {child : {}}

print result
```

Comment: What would the expected output be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a dictionary that maps a name to the corresponding dictionary:

```
items = {}
for parent, child in relations:
    parent_dict = items.setdefault(parent, {})
    child_dict = items.setdefault(child, {})
    if child not in parent_dict:
        parent_dict[child] = child_dict

result = items['basket']  # basket is the top-level item
```

This produces:

```
>>> items = {}
>>> for parent, child in relations:
...     parent_dict = items.setdefault(parent, {})
...     child_dict = items.setdefault(child, {})
...     if child not in parent_dict:
...         parent_dict[child] = child_dict
...
>>> items['basket']
{'money': {}, 'vegetables': {'tomato': {'green tomato': {}, 'red tomato': {}}, 'bean': {}, 'pepper': {}}, 'fruits': {'orange': {}, 'apple': {}}}
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(items['basket'])
{'fruits': {'apple': {}, 'orange': {}},
 'money': {},
 'vegetables': {'bean': {},
                'pepper': {},
                'tomato': {'green tomato': {}, 'red tomato': {}}}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I played around with your example and eventually got it.